# Chutzpah.json file references missing when running Jasmine tests via Resharper

Tags: javascript, resharper, chutzpah

Is there a way for Resharper's javascript test runner to load references specified in a **Chutzpah.json** file?

My tests run successfully in the Visual Studio Test Explorer and on my TFS build server.

When ran via the Resharper test runner they fail due to missing file references.